# Convert double to int without loss of precision in java

Tags: java, integer, double

I would like to convert a double (for example price with a value of 1.90) to an integer without losses! I am making a program that processes money, and I have to input them as doubles, and then convert them to integers so that I can proccess them and for example when I have 1.90 euros and i want to convert it to cents it will appear as 189 cents instead of 190! please help me :) thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please provide an example of what you have (7.90) and what you want as output ? (789? 790?)

Comment: @TheoBabilon Another example! I have 1.5 and I want to convert it to 150 not 149

Comment: @KritonGeorgiou: Theo's point was: show your code.

Comment: @Stultuske I have to show 64 lines of code! I just want to import money as doubles in the format of 0.1 or 0.2 or 1 and convert it to double!

Comment: You have 64 lines of code for converting a double to an int?

Comment: No, you don't have to show 64 lines of code. You need to show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. Note that I wouldn't expect you to have any problems with 1.5, but I would expect problems with 0.1 or 0.2 as they can't be represented precisely with `double`. You should consider using `BigDecimal`.

Comment: @Manu I am making a program that imports money and gives tickets! the issue is that i have to convert to int without issues

Comment: @KritonGeorgiou: that takes one or two lines, not 64 lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the details on how doubles and floats behave in java in the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3)

Well, you could round the value to desired precision. As long as you're within given [format's precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) (~15 digits for double ~7 for float) you'll get good results.

```
double fractValue = 1.90; // 1.8999999....
int val = (int)Math.round(fractValue*100);
```

It's much better idea to use `BigDecimal` though. You will never lose any precision then.

Comment: well thanks that was the best solution of all and solved my issue! thanks a lot!!!!!

Comment: Just on the "BigDecimal". Unless you need fractions of a cent/pence/whatever I'd use int (as number of cents) everywhere. BigDecimal feels to me to be overkill if you are always working in complete cents.

Answer (score -1):

```
double x = 1.89; //Or whatever
String[] y = String.valueOf(x).split("[.]");  // Returns array having 1 and 89
String z = y[0] + y[1];  //String which is = 189
    if(y[1].length()==1)
        z +="0";  // Add a 0 in end if required
int finalInt = Integer.parseInt(z);  //Convert String to Integer
```

`finalInt` should be what you want.

Comment: `parseDouble` does not take a `Double` as argument.

Comment: Also, double --> String --> int is a bit of a detour.